# I downloaded quickstart (angularjs2) from angular.io but after start npm is showing error

Tags: angular

1. angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start G:\quickstart\quickstart-master
       tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"

   [1] 'lite-server' is not recognized as an internal or external
   command,
   [1] operable program or batch file.
   [1] lite-server
   exited with code 1    [0] 10:43:05 PM - Compilation complete.
   Watching for file changes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your forgot to do `npm install`

After that run, `npm start`